# Calling a C library method from swift using pointers

Tags: c, swift

Given the following **ODBC C API** information and associated type definitions, how does one call the **SQLSetEnvAttr** function from **swift**?

From **swift**, my code successfully invokes the prerequisite **SQLAllocHandle** function which provides the handle to the environment (**henv**) utilized in the subsequent **SQLSetEnvAttr** function call.
I have tried a variety of approaches including **UnsafeMutablePointer**, attempting to follow instructions referenced on the following sites, but I couldn't figure out how to get the compiler to allow me to convert from a **Void *** to a **SQLPOINTER** (even though it is defined to be the same thing).  Additionally, I was stymied on how to make the **UnsafeMutablePointer** point to the value of the **CUnsignedLong** variable (**SQL_OV_ODBC3** typedef) I used (set to **3**)

- http://www.sitepoint.com/using-legacy-c-apis-swift/
- http://chris.eidhof.nl/posts/swift-c-interop.html

**ODBC API**

```
typedef signed short int SQLSMALLINT;
typedef SQLSMALLINT     SQLRETURN;
typedef void *          SQLPOINTER;
#define SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION               200
#define SQL_OV_ODBC3                        3UL

retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,
             (SQLPOINTER) SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
```

The working **swift** code that gets me the handle to the environment is:

`var sqlHenvPtr : UnsafeMutablePointer<SQLHENV> = UnsafeMutablePointer<SQLHENV>.alloc(1)
var retcode : CShort = SQLAllocHandle(Int16(SQL_HANDLE_ENV), nil, sqlHenvPtr)`

Looking for help with how to define and pass the third parameter:

```
let SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION : Int32 = 200
retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlHenvPtr.memory, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, ???, 0)
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: there is a `;` missing on the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated per Chris's feedback**

```
let value = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(bitPattern: 3)
SQLSetEnvAttr(0, 0, value, 0)
```

The expected value by *SQLSetEnvAttr()* is **0x3** (in your case it was **0x10025a478**). I verified that my own prototype C function which accepts *SQLPOINTER* receives **0x3** in case of preparing 3rd parameter in proposed way. Hope it helps now.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work.  The odbc trace log indicates that it is not getting a good value (it shows Value = 0x10025a478)      : `[ODBC][38835][1460842352.600781][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][189]
  Entry:
   Environment = 0x102800600
   Attribute = SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION
   Value = 0x10025a478
   StrLen = 0
[ODBC][38835][1460842352.600897][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][257]Error: HY024`  The C invocation in a program that works properly looks like this `retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,
                 (SQLPOINTER) SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);`

Comment: Using your updated code worked!  Thank you very much.  The ODBC trace after the update: `[ODBC][39224][1460889123.575242][__handles.c][460]
  Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
   Environment = 0x101801a00
[ODBC][39224][1460889123.575870][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][189]
  Entry:
   Environment = 0x101801a00
   Attribute = SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION
   Value = 0x3
   StrLen = 0
[ODBC][39224][1460889123.575945][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][364]`

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!